# Rotation Matrix when moving in one direction

Tags: computer-vision

Assuming I have a camera mounted in a rail, I can move it back and forth to take photos of my scene.

Can I assume I have a Rotation Matrix equal to zero?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the coordinate system you choose. Assuming it's aligned with your camera rotation (e.g. negative Z-axis into viewing direction of the camera and positive y-axis points upwards) and you only move your camera without rotating it, then the rotation matrix, which is used to transform between these coordinate system is the **Identity** matrix. 
A zero matrix makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume no rotation, then the rotation matrix is a 3x3 identity matrix, not zero.

Also, this may or may not be a good assumption depending on how accurate you want to be. Even if the camera is moving on a rail, there will be some small rotation.

Comment: Correct, Identity matrix not zero. I just need to get an estimation of the depth map. Thanks